# Sending Stock Update Email Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have been working on this stock update email alert module for my Magento store and I based my code on [a magento stack exchange thread here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/daily-admin-email-for-products-that-went-out-of-stock-that-day). After much fiddling I got my own version to work. I was wondering why the example code did not work:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function lowStockReport($observer)
    {
        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent();

        if($stockItem->getQty() < $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty()){

            //stock is lower than the notify amount, send email

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stockItem->getProductId());

            $body = "{$product->getName()} :: {$product->getSku()} just Ran out of stock:\n\n";
            $body .= "Current Qty: {$stockItem->getQty()}\n";
            $body .= "Low Stock Date: {$stockItem->getLowStockDate()}\n";

            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            $mail->setFrom('lowstock@yourwebsite.com', 'Low Stock Notifier');
            $mail->addTo('youremail@gmail.com', 'Your Name Here');
            $mail->setSubject('[Notice] An Item Has Gone Out of Stock');
            $mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

However, my dirtier code did work just fine:

```
class Custom_Stockupdate_Model_Observer
{

    public function lowStockReport($observer)
    {

        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent();
        $myItem = ($stockItem->debug());

        $theQty = $myItem['data_object (Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)']['qty'];
        $theId = $myItem['data_object (Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)']['product_id'];
        if($theQty == '0'){
            //stock is lower than the notify amount, send email

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($theId);

            $body = "{$product->getName()} :: {$product->getSku()} just Ran out of stock:\n\n";
            $body .= "Current Qty: {$theQty}\n";

            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            $mail->setFrom('lowstock@yourwebsite.com', 'Low Stock Notifier');
            $mail->addTo('youremail@gmail.com', 'Your Name Here');
            $mail->setSubject('[Notice] An Item Has Gone Out of Stock');
            $mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

Any critiques and best practices I missed would be much appreciated since I am still a novice.

Comment: Are you sure that $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty() is bigger than $stockItem->getQty()? Could you check both values?

Comment: That was my first inkling that the values were somehow not pulling or null. they both return null values when I outputted them to the mage::log(). My guess at the time was that  the calls to the object methods getNotifyStockQty()  and  getQty() didn't exist for that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think, you have to change

```
$stockItem = $observer->getEvent();
```

into

```
$stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($observer->getEvent()->getProductId());
if ($stockItem->getQty() < $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty()) {
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick responses. I just wanted to post my final "cleaner" solution. 
I also added a check to see if the product is a "grouped" product because if not it will shoot off an email everytime a change is made to a parent SKU.

```
class Custom_Stockupdate_Model_Observer
{

    public function lowStockReport($observer)
    {

        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stockItem->getProductId());

        if($stockItem->getQty() < $stockItem->getNotifyStockQty() && $product->getTypeID() !== "grouped"){
            //stock is lower than the notify amount, send email


            $body = "{$product->getName()} :: {$product->getSku()} just Ran out of stock:\n\n";
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            $mail->setFrom('lowstock@yourwebsite.com', 'Low Stock Notifier');
            $mail->addTo('youremail@gmail.com', 'Your Name Here');
            $mail->setSubject('[Notice] An Item Has Gone Out of Stock');
            $mail->send();
```